# Add submenu entry to WooCommerce "Products" admin menu

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, backend, hook-woocommerce

I would like to add a submenu entry under the WooCommerce "Products" admin menu. Does anybody know what the $parent_slug for this menu is?

I can add a submenu item to the "WooCommerce" menu using `add_submenu_page` and 'woocommerce' for `$parent_slug` (via the `admin_menu` hook), but can't seem to figure out what the `$parent_slug` for the Products menu is...

```php
if ( is_admin() ) {
    add_action( 'admin_menu', 'add_products_menu_entry', 100 );
}

function add_products_menu_entry() {
    add_submenu_page(
        'woocommerce-product', // This is what I can't figure out
        __( 'Product Grabber' ),
        __( 'Grab New' ),
        'manage_woocommerce', // Required user capability
        'ddg-product',
        'generate_grab_product_page'
    );
}

function generate_grab_product_page() {
  // Page generation code will go here
}
```

WooCommerce Products Admin Menu

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Got it, it was `edit.php?post_type=product`

```
if ( is_admin() ) {
    add_action( 'admin_menu', 'add_products_menu_entry', 100 );
}

function add_products_menu_entry() {
    add_submenu_page(
        'edit.php?post_type=product',
        __( 'Product Grabber' ),
        __( 'Grab New' ),
        'manage_woocommerce', // Required user capability
        'ddg-product',
        'generate_grab_product_page'
    );
}

function generate_grab_product_page() {
  echo "<h2>Hello, it worked! :-)</h2>";
}
```

Thank-you to Derick Rethans / XDebug!

Answer (score 0):

It worked using the following invocation:

```
add_submenu_page(
    'edit.php?post_type=product',
    'My Custom Submenu Page',
    'My Custom Submenu Page',
    'manage_options',
    'create-child-product',
    'display_create_child_product_page'
);
```